# I cannot debug two projects at once - one with Resharper NUnit tests

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, nunit, resharper

My team has a solution with multiple projects.  One of these projects is an ASP.NET MVC website.  Another project contains NUnit tests.  We launch these NUnit tests inside Visual Studio 2013 with Resharper 8.2.2.

Another developer on my team is able debug both the MVC project and the NUnit tests simultaneously.  He starts a debugging session (simple press of f5) and then can select debug from the Resharper menu:

[image: Debug is available]

For me, however, once the MVC project is debugging, my Resharper debug option is greyed-out:

[image: Debug is not available]

What setting am I likely missing?  I've looked through our user- and computer-specific Resharper settings and haven't seen any differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the ability to debug unit tests while other projects are running is a feature that was introduced in Resharper 9.x.  The other developer was using a trial of it, it turns out.  Now that he's reverted back to 8.2.2, he is seeing the same thing that I was seeing.